# Rails: How exactly does the "shallow" option benefit us?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i've been learning rails for a little bit. Sometimes routing I get confused on (Well not so much confused but just figuring out "best practices").

One thing i've never used is the "shallow" option, such as in this example in the docs:

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
resources :comments, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Which is what shallow would do if just appended onto the `:comments` portion.

So how exactly is this a benefit? does it just basically prevent the paths from being /articles/comments/:id for multiple things and instead just being /comments/:id for the methods? Unless im missing something?

Comment: Basically you don't want routes looking like this: `/articles/1/comments/2/users/new`. In this case the article with ID=1 is already inferred due to the fact that you have a comment with ID=2. So in this case, you want to create a more shallow route, that points to: `/comments/2/users/new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.

Keeping this in mind we always try to avoid deep nesting.

`shallow` option is just used to avoid complicated(deeply) nested routes wherever possible. It should be used only for the resources which are bound to their parents.